# Nhibernate escaping special character within linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a table like:

**TABLE_XY**

```
|ID |SOURCE|
|1  |value_aa|
|2  |other_aa|
|3  |eeeaa|
```

And the generated query should be:

```
select * from TABLE_XY where SOURCE like '%\_aa' ESCAPE '\'​
```

I know that there are two options which would fit my needs

```
var result = 
            session.QueryOver<TableXy>()
            .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.Source)
            .IsLike("%\_aa", MatchMode.Exact, '\\')
            .List();
```

or

```
var result2 = session
     .CreateCriteria<TableXy>()
     .Add(LikeExpression("Source", "%\\_aa", MatchMode.Exact, '\\', false))
     .List();
```

But I have to use a Linq based implementation. I'm working with dynamically created expression trees, which sometimes will be executed with the Linq to Object Provider or Linq to Nhibernate. 
But currently only this method is supported:

```
  var result = session
       .Query<TableXy>()
       .Where(x => NHibernate.Linq.SqlMethods.Like(x.Source, "%\\_aa"))
       .ToList();
```

How can I extend the Nhibernate Linq Provider to support?

```
SqlMethods.IsLike(string source, string pattern, char? escape);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, this is a pretty involved answer and there may very well be problems with it, but I was able to get a `like` operator with an `escape` piece working.

This involves a few steps, but basically what we're doing is adding a new type of `HqlTreeNode` that can handle the `escape` portion of the `like` operator.

1. Create an extension method that you'll use in LINQ queries. This method does not need an implementation--we'll provide that later:

   ```
   public static class LinqExtensions
   {
       public static bool IsLikeWithEscapeChar(
           this string input,
           string like,
           char? escapeChar)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an `HqlEscape` tree node that we will use to represent the `escape` portion of the `like` operator:

   ```
   public class HqlEscape : HqlExpression
   {
       public HqlEscape(IASTFactory factory, params HqlTreeNode[] children)
           : base(HqlSqlWalker.ESCAPE, "escape", factory, children)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an `HqlLikeWithEscape` tree node. The default `HqlLike` node cannot handle the `escape` part, so we need to create a new node that can handle three children:

   ```
   public class HqlLikeWithEscape : HqlBooleanExpression
   {
       public HqlLikeWithEscape(IASTFactory factory, HqlExpression lhs, HqlExpression rhs, HqlEscape escape)
           : base(HqlSqlWalker.LIKE, "like", factory, lhs, rhs, escape)
       {
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a generator for the `IsLikeWithEscapeChar` extension method we defined earlier. This class' responsibility is to take the information the method is invoked with and return an HQL tree structure that will ultimately be turned into SQL:

   ```
   public class CustomLikeGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForMethod
   {
       public CustomLikeGenerator()
       {
           this.SupportedMethods = new[]
           {
               ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(
                   () => LinqExtensions.IsLikeWithEscapeChar(null, null, null))
           };
       }

       public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(
           MethodInfo method,
           System.Linq.Expressions.Expression targetObject,
           ReadOnlyCollection<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression> arguments,
           HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
       {
           // Is there a better way to do this?
           var factory = new ASTFactory(new ASTTreeAdaptor());
           HqlTreeNode escapeCharNode = visitor.Visit(arguments[2]).AsExpression();
           var escapeNode = new HqlEscape(factory, escapeCharNode);

           HqlLikeWithEscape likeClauseNode =
               new HqlLikeWithEscape(
                   factory,
                   visitor.Visit(arguments[0]).AsExpression(),
                   visitor.Visit(arguments[1]).AsExpression(),
                   escapeNode);

           return likeClauseNode;
       }
   }
   ```

   As you can see, we've utilized the new HQL tree nodes we defined earlier. The major downside to this approach is that it required me to manually create an `ASTFactory` and `ASTTreeAdaptor`. The use of these classes is usually encapsulated inside of `HqlTreeBuilder`, but `HqlTreeBuilder` doesn't lend itself to being subclassed. Would appreciate some input on this if someone has some advice.
5. Create a new LINQ to HQL generators registry. This class just just associates our extension method with the HQL implementation we provided in step 4:

   ```
   public class LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
   {
       public LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry() : base()
       {
           RegisterGenerator(
               ReflectionHelper.GetMethodDefinition(() => LinqExtensions.IsLikeWithEscapeChar(null, null, null)),
               new CustomLikeGenerator());
       }
   }
   ```
6. Update your configuration to use the new `LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry`:

   ```
   cfg.LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry<LinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry>();
   ```
7. (Finally) use your new extension method in a query:

   ```
   session.Query<Person>().Where(p => p.FirstName.IsLikeWithEscapeChar("%Foo", '\\'))
   ```

   Note that you need to specify the wildcard character. This could be smoothed out, but that wouldn't be too hard to do.

This is the first time I've extended HQL this way so again, there could be issues with this solution. I was only able to test on SQL Server, but I'm reasonable confident it should work given that it creates the same tree structure that an HQL query does.

Comment: Nice! Your solution works as I expected!  The only change I've made: Instead of creating a new ASTFactory I do this `var factory = treeBuilder.Constant(null).Factory` to get the internal factory. I don't if this is 100% correct but it works

Answer (score 1):

Solution here, should be surprisingly simple:

```
var result = session
    .Query<TableXy>()

    // instead of this
    //.Where(x => NHibernate.Linq.SqlMethods.Like(x.Source, "%\\_aa"))

    // This will add sign % at the beginning only
    .Where(x => x.Source.EndsWith("[_]aa"));
    // or wrap it on both sides with sign: % 

    .Where(x => x.Source.Contains("[_]aa"));
    .ToList();
```

Trick is to use *ruglar like expression* style for underscore **`[_]`**

Comment: Well this solution works with MS-SQL but not with Oracle Databases.

Comment: Most likely yes... MS SQL server does support regular expressions like this. yes... But honestly no such experience with Oracle... sorry. But you still can use methods like **`EndsWith()`**, **`StartsWith()`**, **`Contains()`** ... and pass the Oracle like styled expression. That should be the way...

Comment: Nope sadly not  when I do something like Contains("%_aa") this would return values "val_aa" and "valaa". which is wrong. if I do Contains("%\\_aa") nothing gets returned at all. I need to somehow pass the escape char to the server

Comment: I cannot test Oracle, but this could/should work `.EndsWith(@"_aa"))` *(is working for SQL Server as well)*

Comment: Sadly this approach returns too much entries since the "_"  will be interpreted as any character so "_aa" or "1aa" or "Xaa" will match the criteria as well